# Android, can't assign a value to the TextView

Tags: android, database, http

I do read the data via http, but I can't assign this data to a TextView.

When I create a TextView in the xml file, the data is assigned to normal. But when I create a TextView programmatically, the text is empty.

```
public class News extends Activity
{
    TextView myText;
    TextView title1;
    String s = "";

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "ResourceAsColor" }) @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news);

        StrictMode.enableDefaults();

        int textId1 = 1;
        int textId2 = 2;

        title1 = new TextView(this);
        title1.setText("Заголовок новости 1  -  2013.01.01\n\nСегодня состоится заседание зампредпал тра та та");
        title1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWihte));
        title1.setShadowLayer(2, 0, 0,getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
        title1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_block));
        title1.setId(textId1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        layoutParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        title1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
        ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.newslayout)).addView(title1);

        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;

        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://test.ivanov-vladimir.com/get_content.php");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "HTTP connect error " + e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                builder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            isr.close();
            result = builder.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Data converting error " + e.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject json = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                s = "Title: " + json.getString("title") + "\n\nContent: " + json.getString("content");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Data parsing error " + e.toString());
        }

        title1.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying assign to the element title1 the last value of the array **jarray.**

This code I got in a video tutorial on YouTube.

If you go to a url http://test.ivanov-vladimir.com/get_content.php will be printed symbols, because the text in the database in Cyrillic.

Comment: `HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);` you should be usign `thread` or `asynctask` for network related operation

Comment: Adapt your code to use Async for network requests, or it will crash on android version >=3.0 http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

First, try avoiding long operations like networking operations in the UI thread, it will slow down your app.

Then, try getting back the TextView value and logging it in order to see if a value is assigned to the TextView :

```
Log.v("TextView value", title1.getText().toString());
```

Then, you can also try to log the content download from your webservice :

```
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    builder.append(line + "\n");
    Log.v("line", line);
}
```

Please provide us the log results.

Comment: Thakt you, i forgot to add INTERNET premission in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: You're welcome! Forgetting to add Internet permission is indeed a common mistake that I also do often! Could you accept this answer if it has helped you? Thanks!